# iOS Storyboard Back Button

Tags: ios, xcode

Im trying to create "push" screen. And My back button text is "Back" despite of his "father" screen title. Moreover, when I try to change text in interface builder of Xcode, it doesn't change my back button text. How can I change it by using Xcode interface builder (storyboard)?

Comment: duplicate question.reffer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553651/uinavigationcontroller-back-button-title-always-show-back/24553774#24553774

Comment: No it is not. I want to change it by using INTERFACE BUILDER

Comment: if the title is short enf. it shud show.check is there any setting self.title in ur view controller

Comment: If you are using storyboard than change fathers "Back Button" property from Navigation Item to "Back"

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:
[image: CustomBack_XCODE]

**Result:**

[image: CustomBack_SIMULATOR]

**Important:** you should specify Back Button text not for the VC where you see back button but for the VC that is the "parent" of the desired screen.

Comment: Thank you for such a detail answer!

Comment: Is there any way to change back button title in all viewcontroller with single line of code at single place?

Comment: I changed its image but the left arrow remains visible. is it possible to remove it?

Comment: The "Important" is really IMPORTANT!

Comment: OMG. I would never guessed that I have to change the "Back button" property of PREVIOUS view, not the current one. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when this item is missing?

Comment: Hi all, I follow the answer and tried settings the Back Button text on parent of desired screen, but still did not appear Back Button text in my desired screen. Which part is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is by any chance the title very long? In that case the back button text will be changed to localized 'Back'. If that is the case try with shorter text or specify a shorter text in the father's navigation item back button property.

Comment: Your 'father' view controller has a navigation item in the storyboard, doesn't it? Select the navigation item and go to it's properties inspector. There you will find the back button property.