# iPhone change back button title without code

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

[image]

We have navigator when we get second page automatically back button title wrote Back we want to write our own language back (Geri) 
We tried change Back Button title on navigator item settings but back title did not change. If there is no solution without writing code, you can give us code example

NOTE : Previous page got title still write Back 
Thank you.

Comment: Which navigation item are you editing? You should edit the navigation item of the *previous* view controller (the one before the screen you want to change the back button in). Editing the *Tarif* back button text will make that effective on the next view controller that you push.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Storyboard Back Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693248/ios-storyboard-back-button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should define back button not for the view that displays button but for the the view that had beed displayed before current one.

Looks at answer for this question: [iOS Storyboard Back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693248/ios-storyboard-back-button/24695475#24695475)