# Cannot have the father uiViewController with the back item?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have seen this topic ([iOS Storyboard Back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693248/ios-storyboard-back-button)) and more about this subject, but I still cannot have my back button appear on screen :

I have got 2 viewControllers, the two of them have a navigationController, the "father" controller has the button bar item set to "back" as a plain text, the second viewController appear well with a modal segue, or with "show detail (replace)" segue, but nothing appear on the navigation bar to come back...  Would you know why?

Here is a capture :

[image]

Thanks

---

EDIT :

with a custom transition, and when presenting the controller via the navigator in the code, the back button is not here anymore... would someone know why?

When I comment out `presentViewController:secondViewController`, the back button is here, but the custom animation is not triggered anymore, there is the normal transition set in the storyboard.

Here is my method :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"segue descr %@ : ", [[sender class] description] );
    if ( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"second"] ){

        //SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

        SecondViewController *secondViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        secondViewController.transitioningDelegate = self;

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:secondViewController
                                                animated:YES
                                              completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal and show detail segues don't use a back button, because they are like independent views.

The idea is that those those views are only showing extra information or details about something and you can close them programmatically when you need to go back to the previous view.

A show or push segue will give you the back button in your navigation controller, because that segue is meant to be more like a sequence of views.

Comment: argh thank you very much, I thought about that but I changed for the wrong one. Thank you for the answer

Comment: would you know why the back button is not where it was, when I use a presentViewController to add a custom transition ? I edited my post above...

Answer (score 1):

When you push a View Controller, you get the back button for "free" without having to write extra code. When you present a modal View Controller, you need to add your own way of dismissing the modal view. Since you have a Navigation Controller, your easiest route is probably to add a UIBarButtonItem to the navigation bar, and have that bar button call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` in your UIViewController subclass.

Comment: Thank you very much Adam for the answer