# Navigation controller back button doesnt appear?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, storyboard

I'm trying to setup back button on the navigation controller but it doesn't appear when I run it. I watched some tutorials and it usually works.[image]

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24695475/3411787),To see button on IB Add `UIButton` from `Object Library`.

Comment: you need to move navigation controller in the front of your menu VC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your flow should be:

NavigationController --> MainVC --> FoodVC

Now you can add button as follow:

Navigation Item -> Left Bar Button Items -> Bar Button Item -> back button

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Go to navigation controller scene -> navigation controller ->navigation bar - then go to right top show attributes option and change bar tint color.Try it

Answer (score 0):

The view controller food is embedded in Navigation Controller , hence it is root view controller.
Navigation bar will appear when any viewController is push on same navigation controller.

So, If you tableview is already in Navigationcontroller then remove Navigation Controller in which Your FoodVC Controller is embedded.

If you want that navigation controller, you may add leftBarButtonItem programatically.

Totally depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Is MenuVc your main Controller? try this, delete that navigation controller in the middle. Then click the MenuVc, embed in Navigation Controller and set the navigation controller as initial view controller at the attribute inspector. then navigate the menuVC to Food, "Show".