# xcode swift - Cannot edit back button

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a table view with a "+" bar button item that segues(Show push) to a UI view. When I added the segue, a back button was automatically added for me with the table view's title. However I can't seem to edit that button or at least hide it? It doesn't allows me to click/highlight on it.

[image]

In the pic above I'm trying to edit the left bar button item "Favorite Foods" on the UI view, any hints? Using Xcode 11 and swift 5.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the navigation bar in the view controller you are pushing using:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true/false)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true/false)
}
```

This code will hide the navigation bar, including the back button on the pushed view controller, and will unhide it when leaving that view controller.

To change the title of the back button to anything, put the following code in the parent view controller, so the view controller which opens the view controller in which you want the back button title to be different:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Whatever text you want", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. select first VC
2. search Navigation Item of the view controller in document outline
3. change the text in attribute inspector (right bar)

refer to this post [iOS Storyboard Back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693248/ios-storyboard-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

“Favorite Foods” is not a left bar button. It is a back bar button. And it belongs to the table view controller, not the second view controller; in particular, to its navigation item. Look at the UINavigationItem docs for things you can do:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem

They include `hidesBackButton`. If you want to show it but use a different title, set the `backBarButtonItem`.